# allow merge html table row using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I Have following table in my angular template
[image]

i need to allow users to merge rows manually when clicking on a icon between the rows (red arrow icon in between row )

**please note that when user click on the arrow icon one row will merged at a time and also when user click on a already merged row, current clicking row will merge with the row bellow that row**

here are the possible row merges

[image]

*final out come should be as follow*

[image]

here what I have tried so far

```
rowsSpanned(currentRow, rowIndex, colIndex, columns) {

    let currentColumn = currentRow.cols[colIndex];
    const currentColumnRowSpan = (currentColumn.rowspan || 1);
            
    let nextRowFollowingColumn;
            
    nextRowFollowingColumn = this.table.rows[rowIndex + currentColumnRowSpan].cols[colIndex];
    //copy next merging row column item to current row column
    currentColumn.items =[...currentColumn.items.concat(nextRowFollowingColumn.items)]; 
    //merged the row
    this.table.rows[rowIndex + currentColumnRowSpan].cols.splice(colIndex, 1); 
            
    currentColumn.rowspan =  currentColumnRowSpan +( nextRowFollowingColumn.rowspan || 1);
            
}
```

Comment: You provided a goal and some code but no specific problem statement or question. What's your question?

Comment: ok @charlietfl it is a goal i have actually my problem is when i m trying to merge row with bellow i cant get exact column index to merge (when i have some other merged rows before that column index)

Comment: lets say we follow these steps step 1 : I merge 4th cell inside row number 2 (ie . rowIndex = 1 column index 3) with row number 3 (ie . rowIndex = 2 column index =3) step 2 : this time i try to merge row number 3 with bellow cell ( rowIndex =4 column index =4)of that row this time i cannot find exact column to merge because i need to copy the items inside the cell